# How can I display comments from a facebook page on another company's website?

Tags: facebook, cross-platform, comments, cross-domain, facebook-comments

We are partnering with another company that has a page on Facebook, and we are looking for the best way to display the comments from that page on our website (and vice versa).  What is the best way to do this since it is not our FB page?

Comment: You would have to create an access token with permissions to access the wall of the app and use the open graph API.

Comment: Your question is pretty terse and ambiguous.  Please clarify what you mean by "comments from that app"

Comment: @Pat Just clarified the requirements and what is needed is the ability to display comments written on their Facebook page (not a FB app) on our site and the ability for people to post on our site and have them appear on their Facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a like box http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

If you want more than that you basically have to implement a facebook application that can handle the data. Think of this as writing your own facebook client like a version of hootsuite. You will need full control of the target page to install the application.

Also when you say "our website" I assume you don't mean a facebook page.